# How to build a ruby template for localized month names in a select/option list

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Struggling to figure out how to create a list of localized months in a  tag via my template.  It's working fine with localized months when I hand-build in the template, but looking for a short-cut to trim my code down.

This is the one giving me trouble:

```
<%= select("month", "exp_month", (1..12).step(1).collect {|m| [ "date.month_names[#{m}]", m ] }) %>
```

It creates a valid select/option list, but the values are literally:

```
date.month_names[1]
date.month_names[2]
…
date.month_names[12]
```

This hand-built code works just fine - but looking for a more elegant short-cut:

```
        <select>
          <option value="01"><%=t("date.month_names")[1] %></option>
          <option value="02"><%=t("date.month_names")[2] %></option>
          <option value="03"><%=t("date.month_names")[3] %></option>
          <option value="04"><%=t("date.month_names")[4] %></option>
          <option value="05"><%=t("date.month_names")[5] %></option>
          <option value="06"><%=t("date.month_names")[6] %></option>
          <option value="07"><%=t("date.month_names")[7] %></option>
          <option value="08"><%=t("date.month_names")[8] %></option>
          <option value="09"><%=t("date.month_names")[9] %></option>
          <option value="10"><%=t("date.month_names")[10] %></option>
          <option value="11"><%=t("date.month_names")[11] %></option>
          <option value="12"><%=t("date.month_names")[12] %></option>
        </select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= select("month", "exp_month", (1..12).collect {|m| [ t("date.month_names")[m], m ] }) %>
```

Comment: Brilliant! That was it!  Thanks so much!  That was killing me for the past two hours!